# MacOS Catalina (10.15) - Fast battery drain!

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

Good afternoon!

I have been experiencing major battery drain issues on my Macbook Pro 2019 (Catalina 10.15.1) since I received it around 2 months ago. Also the version before Catalina (Mojave 10.14.5 (18F203)) had exactly the same issues for me.

The battery just drains extremely quickly, maybe having 2-3 hours of normal use. Moreover, from 100% battery in the evening, I close the lid, and in the morning the battery is at 0%.

One thing I noticed is that the kernel_task disk usage is 2.04 TB after around 1 week of usage, while on another Mac is around 7-10 GB after 1 week of usage.There are no processes that are consuming memory, CPU or battery in the Activity Monitor. What could be the issue?

I attached a log file with all wake up reasons during last night. What seems to always wake the Mac up almost every minute is EC.RTC (Alarm). Google didn't really help me understand what it is or what it does.

```
2019-11-19 04:21:25.633316+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2019-11-19 04:21:25.633317+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2019-11-19 04:22:27.831079+0100  localhost rapportd[622]: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.CoreUtils:CUSleepWakeMonitor] CLink: State changed: Sleep -> DarkWake, 0x1 < DarkWake >
2019-11-19 04:22:27.901747+0100  localhost bluetoothd[132]: (SPOwner) [com.apple.icloud.SPOwner:powerManagement] Wake time calculated as - [Tue Nov 19 07:17:50 2019]
2019-11-19 04:22:28.232409+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-11-19 04:22:28.468557+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleIntelCFLGraphicsFramebuffer) [IGFB][INFO   ] FB0 power state transition Sleep to Doze
2019-11-19 04:22:28.910269+0100  localhost bluetoothd[132]: (SPOwner) [com.apple.icloud.SPOwner:powerManagement] Wake time calculated as - [Tue Nov 19 07:17:50 2019]
2019-11-19 04:22:28.913387+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-11-19 04:22:30.088743+0100  localhost bluetoothd[132]: (IOBluetooth) [com.apple.bluetooth:CBPower] PMConnectionHandler - Dark Wake IOPMSystemPowerStateCapabilities - Sleep
2019-11-19 04:22:30.718738+0100  localhost bluetoothd[132]: (IOBluetooth) [com.apple.bluetooth:CBPower] PMConnectionHandler - Dark Wake IOPMSystemPowerStateCapabilities - Sleep
2019-11-19 04:22:39.516225+0100  localhost powerd[81]: [powerd:sleepWake] Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep'
2019-11-19 04:22:39.516682+0100  localhost rapportd[622]: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.CoreUtils:CUSleepWakeMonitor] CLink: State changed: DarkWake -> Sleep, 0x20 < Sleep >
2019-11-19 04:22:39.516689+0100  localhost rapportd[622]: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.CoreUtils:CUSleepWakeMonitor] CLink: Sleep async ack
2019-11-19 04:22:39.517520+0100  localhost bluetoothd[132]: (SPOwner) [com.apple.icloud.SPOwner:powerManagement] Network off sleep date is not setup yet. Wake date cannot be calculated without baseline.
2019-11-19 04:22:58.716994+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2019-11-19 04:22:58.716996+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2019-11-19 04:24:00.857383+0100  localhost rapportd[622]: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.CoreUtils:CUSleepWakeMonitor] CLink: State changed: Sleep -> DarkWake, 0x1 < DarkWake >
2019-11-19 04:24:00.895338+0100  localhost bluetoothd[132]: (SPOwner) [com.apple.icloud.SPOwner:powerManagement] Wake time calculated as - [Tue Nov 19 07:17:50 2019]
2019-11-19 04:24:01.278851+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-11-19 04:24:01.449828+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleIntelCFLGraphicsFramebuffer) [IGFB][INFO   ] FB0 power state transition Sleep to Doze
2019-11-19 04:24:01.902270+0100  localhost bluetoothd[132]: (SPOwner) [com.apple.icloud.SPOwner:powerManagement] Wake time calculated as - [Tue Nov 19 07:17:50 2019]
2019-11-19 04:24:01.907413+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-11-19 04:24:03.008208+0100  localhost bluetoothd[132]: (IOBluetooth) [com.apple.bluetooth:CBPower] PMConnectionHandler - Dark Wake IOPMSystemPowerStateCapabilities - Sleep
2019-11-19 04:24:03.646996+0100  localhost bluetoothd[132]: (IOBluetooth) [com.apple.bluetooth:CBPower] PMConnectionHandler - Dark Wake IOPMSystemPowerStateCapabilities - Sleep
2019-11-19 04:24:12.446910+0100  localhost powerd[81]: [powerd:sleepWake] Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep'
2019-11-19 04:24:12.447766+0100  localhost rapportd[622]: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.CoreUtils:CUSleepWakeMonitor] CLink: State changed: DarkWake -> Sleep, 0x20 < Sleep >
2019-11-19 04:24:12.447770+0100  localhost rapportd[622]: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.CoreUtils:CUSleepWakeMonitor] CLink: Sleep async ack
2019-11-19 04:24:12.447872+0100  localhost bluetoothd[132]: (SPOwner) [com.apple.icloud.SPOwner:powerManagement] Network off sleep date is not setup yet. Wake date cannot be calculated without baseline.
2019-11-19 04:24:32.671736+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2019-11-19 04:24:32.671737+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2019-11-19 04:25:35.175846+0100  localhost rapportd[622]: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.CoreUtils:CUSleepWakeMonitor] CLink: State changed: Sleep -> DarkWake, 0x1 < DarkWake >
```

Comment: What is the Cycle count of Battery that you can get from System Information?

Comment: @Udhy how can I see that?

Comment: @Simerialonut: To check battery's status, go to Apple menu > Hold Option > "About This Mac" will become "System Information." Click on that Option and select Power.

Comment: @Udhy  Health Information: Cycle Count: 65, Condition: Normal

Comment: I would try SMC reset and NVRAM reset as a first attempt. Your battery life is good so try two reset option and let us know how it works.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063 & https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: @Udhy Resetting SMC and NVRAM helped with battery drain while using the laptop, however overnight I still lost all my battery

Comment: Also, try to boot your machine in Safe mode. Be there for a while and see how the battery behaves. Then, reset SMC and NVRAM after that. Test it, disable Enable Power NAP, enable put hard disk to sleep when possible from Energy Saver in evening time when you close your lid.